# Want to change database dynamically using variable in SQL server, How to do it?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to change database dynamically using variable, but not able to do it.
Following is the script

```
set @query='Use {DBNAME}'

DECLARE @SQL_SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL_SCRIPT = REPLACE(@query, '{DBNAME}', @DatabaseName)
EXECUTE (@SQL_SCRIPT)
```

before this script i have variable @DatabaseName set with diff database name

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your script. The `EXECUTE` is setting new context to the database but you need to append the the other code to the dynamic T-SQL statement as well.

```
DECLARE @SQL_SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DatabaseName SYSNAME 
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DatabaseName = 'master'
set @query='Use {DBNAME}; select db_Name();'


SET @SQL_SCRIPT = REPLACE(@query, '{DBNAME}', @DatabaseName)

EXECUTE (@SQL_SCRIPT);
```

This will give you `master`. So, you can change the context, just add the rest of the code there, in the same T-SQL statement.

Also, you are not allowed to use `GO` in `EXECUTE`/`sp_executesql`.